# Using Ruby DBI's prepare without a handle?

Tags: ruby, dbi

I need to use Ruby to create some SQL statements for a MySQL database.  Ruby will never connect to the database.  The SQL statements will be sent to another site and executed against the MySQL database.

Since the machine running Ruby does not have a connection to the database, is it possible to use DBI's prepare statement without creating a handle to the MySQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ruby-dbi` does include an emulator for preparing statements when the dbd does not provide it.  You can use it as follows:

```
require 'dbi'
st = DBI::SQL::PreparedStatement.new(nil, "Select * from table where x = ?")
st.bind(['test']) # => "Select * from table where x = test"
```

You can see the algorithm it uses [here](http://github.com/erikh/ruby-dbi/blob/master/lib/dbi/sql/preparedstatement.rb).

Edit:  Based on the comments below a, dbi 0.2.2 version

```
require 'dbi'
class Quoter ; include DBI::SQL::BasicQuote ; end
st = DBI::SQL::PreparedStatement.new(Quoter.new, "Select * from table where x = ?")
st.bind(['test']) # => "Select * from table where x = 'test'"
```

Relevant source file is [here](http://github.com/erikh/ruby-dbi/blob/0.2.2/lib/dbi/sql.rb).

Comment: The code above produces an error.  It seems that a quoter class is needed.  --> 

NoMethodError: undefined method `quote' for nil:NilClass
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/dbi/sql.rb:198:in `bind'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/dbi/sql.rb:197:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/dbi/sql.rb:197:in `bind'
        from (irb):15

Comment: Works like a charm in Ruby 1.9.1/ dbi 0.4.3.  What version of dbi/ruby are you on?  We could probably find the corresponding code for that version.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.8.6 / dbi 0.2.2.

Comment: This should work...  On a side note,  you are on a Jurassic platform.  Do consider upgrading.

Comment: Am I missing something?  The newer version doesn't seem to be quoting anything.  Shouldn't `"Select * from table where x = test"` end up as `"Select * from table where x = 'test'"`, as in the 0.2.2 version?